# What is the piecewise defined function for the following.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the differential equation for, with an initial condition of $x(0)=0$:

$$0.2x'(t) + x(t) = 2u(t-1)-2u(t-2)$$

This is the answer I received:

$$x(t) = 2(1-e^{-5(t-1)})u(t-1) - 2(1-e^{-5(t-2)})u(t-2)$$

I went through my process accurately and this should be the right answer.
But now I need to figure out how to write the piecewise defined function which I'm a bit weak at.

Can anyone help? hint or advise?

This is the answer that it should be:

$x(t) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{0 ≤ t < 1} \\
2(1-e^{-5(t-1)}) & \text{1 ≤ t < 2} \\
43756e^{-5t} & \text{2 ≤ t}
\end{cases}$

I can understand why the functions $0$ and $2(1-e^{-5(t-1)})$ and where they came from but where did the $43756e^{-5t}$ come from? should it not be $- 2(1-e^{-5(t-2)})$ does it have something to do with the minus?

If someone could shed light on this situation I would be grateful

Comment: What is $u(t)$?

Comment: Unit step function

Comment: $43756 $ is not very accurate actually it should be $2 e^5 (e^5 - 1)$.

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate on how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: @user202729 please elaborate, I can see how that number can be translated, but I need to know why it's not what I mentioned above

Comment: Quite late, but $x(t) = 2(1-e^{-5(t-1)})u(t-1) - 2(1-e^{-5(t-2)})u(t-2) = 2(1-e^{-5(t-1)}) - 2(1-e^{-5(t-2)})$ for $2 \leq t$. And you can prove $2(1-e^{-5(t-1)}) - 2(1-e^{-5(t-2)}) = 2e^5 (e^5 -1) e^{-5t}$.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider Heaviside step function as:

$$\mathfrak{U}_c(x)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & 0\leq x < c \\
            1 & \quad x > c
        \end{array}
    \right.~~$$ where $c>0$, then it is not so hard seeing that a piecewise continoius function

$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f_1(x) & \quad 0< x<a \\
           f_2(x) & \quad a< x<b\\
           f_3(x) & \quad x>b
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ can be written as $f(x)=f_1-(f_2-f_1)\mathfrak{U}_a(x)+(f_3-f_2)\mathfrak{U}_b(x)$.